# How to echo out 'include_once' inside html

Tags: php

Let's say I have a file which goes like this:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
    $get_cat_pro = "select * from products where cat_id='$cat_id'";
    $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat_pro);
    while($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)){
        $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_cat = $row_cat_pro['cat_id'];
        $pro_brand = $row_cat_pro['brand_id'];
        $pro_desc = $row_cat_pro['product_desc'];
        $pro_price = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_img1'];

        echo "
        <section>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                    "include_once 'php/includes/overall/widget.php'"

                    <div class='col-sm-9 padding-right'>
                        <div class='features_items'><!--features_items-->
                            <h2 class='title text-center'>Products</h2>

                            <ul class='pagination'>
                                <li class='active'><a href="">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>&raquo;</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--features_items-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

And in this file I want to echo out an `include_once` command but I don't know the proper way to do this while echoing some html text.. So I get this error message as well:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include_once' (T_INCLUDE_ONCE), expecting ',' or ';' on line 19

And the line 19 is this:

```
"include_once 'php/includes/overall/widget.php'"
```

So how to correct this issue?

Comment: What is in widget.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to get into PHP context, you have to put `<?php  ?>` tags in your HTML.  Here you are using echo to output HTML from PHP, and requiring to do PHP again.  If you want the HTML to switch to PHP to execute the include_once, you have to put the tags again.  In your code, the include_once is viewed as HTML, which is not correct, hence the error.

But it gets a bit crazy with php that echos HTML, that requires PHP.  So why not simply exit the PHP context to output your html, and get back in for the include_once?

Like so:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['cat_id']))
{
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
    $get_cat_pro = "select * from products where cat_id='$cat_id'";
    $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat_pro);
    while($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro))
    {
        $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_cat = $row_cat_pro['cat_id'];
        $pro_brand = $row_cat_pro['brand_id'];
        $pro_desc = $row_cat_pro['product_desc'];
        $pro_price = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_img1'];
        ?>

        <section>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <?php include_once('php/includes/overall/widget.php'); ?>

                    <div class='col-sm-9 padding-right'>
                        <div class='features_items'><!--features_items-->
                            <h2 class='title text-center'>Products</h2>

                            <ul class='pagination'>
                                <li class='active'><a href="">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>&raquo;</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--features_items-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I can take a -1 like a big boy, but explain why.

Comment: This is right but can u tell me how to echo out `<img src='product_images/$pro_image' alt='$pro_title picture' />` within php ?

Comment: I didn't take -1 to any of the answers!

Comment: @wraimiueahia, do not worry, others did, not you.  For your follow up question, accept an answer here, and start a new one.  But a hint, simply use echo "blablabla".  PHP variables are interpreted within double quoted strings.

Comment: +1 @Nic3500 Well what you have is definitely valid as it clearly shows the separation between the HTML and PHP.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw thants, please feel free to upvote :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 :) I did that is why it's back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

Because you started the echo with `"` you can't have `"` inside it, you can only use `"` again when the echo is ending or when you're connecting it to another string.

As you can see I connected it by using periods like so:

```
...ss='row'>" . include_once ('php/includes/overall/widget.php'); ."<div clas...
```

```html
    <?php 
if(isset($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
    $get_cat_pro = "select * from products where cat_id='$cat_id'";
    $run_cat_pro = mysqli_query($con,$get_cat_pro);
    while($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat_pro)){
        $pro_id = $row_cat_pro['product_id'];
        $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_cat = $row_cat_pro['cat_id'];
        $pro_brand = $row_cat_pro['brand_id'];
        $pro_desc = $row_cat_pro['product_desc'];
        $pro_price = $row_cat_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_img1'];

        echo "
        <section>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>".

                    include_once ('php/includes/overall/widget.php');


                    ."<div class='col-sm-9 padding-right'>
                        <div class='features_items'><!--features_items-->
                            <h2 class='title text-center'>Products</h2>

                            <ul class='pagination'>
                                <li class='active'><a href="">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>&raquo;</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--features_items-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: If he echos the include_once line to the browser, the browser will not know what to do with that, since it is a PHP line.  He forgot to get back into PHP context.

Comment: Then the error would be `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' on line 23`

Comment: @Nic3500 Can u write down what u mean please

Comment: @Nic3500 you're wrong dude - the example I had wrritten above has the include inside the php echo so the php would manage it :)

Comment: Ah I see you added the . to exit the echo statement, ok, -1 removed.

Comment: @Nic3500 Oh okay thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "
        <section>
            <div class='container'>
                <div class='row'>";

                 include_once 'php/includes/overall/widget.php';

                echo " <div class='col-sm-9 padding-right'>
                        <div class='features_items'><!--features_items-->
                            <h2 class='title text-center'>Products</h2>

                            <ul class='pagination'>
                                <li class='active'><a href="">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>2</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>3</a></li>
                                <li><a href=''>&raquo;</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--features_items-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        ";
```

Comment: The include_once can be called many times.  It will be executed only once. require_once would fail.  And his include file might have code that needs to be located there to work.

Comment: Yep, good edit, but Ryan Earnshaw beat you to it :-)  And his answer is better, since he explains it, not just dump code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, since you want to echo a multiline string, I'd use [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

You could use [fread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php). Here's an example of what that would look like.

```
    $str = fread(fopen('php/includes/overall/widget.php', 'a+'), filesize('php/includes/overall/widget.php'));
    echo "
         ALL YOUR HTML
         {$str}
         SOME MORE HTML";
```

Comment: For mentionning Heredoc, +1.  Your no.1 is not valid, the OP did not put a ; in his code in the question.  -1.  No.2 very weird way to do that, since all he has to do is return to PHP context.  Not saying it is invalid, just convoluted compared to other ways PHP provides.  So no +-.  Final score, 0 ;-)

Comment: @Mav If you mean this: http://www.paste.org/88025 , it returns the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '">1</a></li> ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  on line 39`

Comment: @Nic3500 I probably saw another answer's semicolon, sorry for that.

Comment: @wraimiueahia that error exists because the anchor tag on line 29 has a double quote, and PHP interprets that as the end of the string you're printing.